# Function with confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this function, I want to add a name in my confirm dialog. The will will be coming from the php code.The problem is it the confirmation is not coming out.

```
function confirmDelete() {
    var delName = "<?php echo $fullName; ?>";
    var del_name = delName;

    if (confirm("Delete " + del_name +) == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an extra `+` after `del_name`. Isn't that causing a syntax error?

Answer (score 2):

You have to delete your extra `+` in your `confirm`!

So it should look like this:

```
function confirmDelete() {
    var delName = "<?php echo $fullName; ?>";
    var del_name = delName;

    if (confirm("Delete " + del_name) == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Another way you can go is to `return` the `confirm()` with out an `if/else` statement and you don't need the variables like this:

```
function confirmDelete() {
    return confirm("Delete " + "<?php echo $fullName; ?>");
}
```

Comment: Why not just `return confirm("Delete " + del_name);` rather than the `if/else`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I wanted to change the code as little as possible for OP, but i will append it as another solution. Thanks!

Comment: I follow a different approach.  I explain what was required to fix the problem in words and then I improve the code in other ways that are apparent and show that too.  IMO, that makes a better answer and that's what we're trying here is to make the best answer we can.  Anyway, glad you added the simplification.  I'm also wondering why the OP defines both `delName` and `del_name`.  Only one is needed.